# SuperMicro Servers can't detect ALL Disk attached to SAS

Tags: sas, supermicro

I got a used Supermicro server with no drives in it. When I plug in a SATA drive it detects it just fine but when I plug in a SAS drive BIOS not detect the SAS drive. FreeNas OS not detect SAS Storge.
It looks like the backplane has SAS connectors on it, but I'm not sure if the motherboard supports it, or if there is some sort of configuration needed to enable it. I've reset the CMOS to see if that helped but it did not.
PCI CARD: Areca ARC-1680ix-24 SAS RAID controllers
Product Name: X8DTH-IF

even after change with another SAS PCI CARD: Areca ARC-1680ix-24, it is not detecting PCI CARD.